# Как задать минимальную ширину окна браузера CSS?

Tags: css

Я хочу чтобы по достижении минимальной ширины в 320px документ перестал сжиматься и появился горизонтальный скролл. В самом документе есть много элементов, выходящих на его границы, поэтому `body{overflow-x:hidden;}` как это можно сделать?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  min-width: 320px;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
}

.content {
  height: 20px;
  width: 5000px;
  background: #FFC;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='content'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: у вас ошибка - "min-widht"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  min-width: 320px;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
}

.content {
  height: 20px;
  width: 5000px;
  background: #FFC;
}
/*выбери любую ширину меняя max-width */
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
 
  <div class='content'>erwew</div>
```

Comment: Это не то. Все элементы content, что были до этого скрыты (не спроста) станут открыты. Нужно чтобы они и остались скрыты. Ширина документа была не меньше 320px а если окно сужается и становится меньше 320px, то появляется горизонтальный скролл и можно прокрутить документ в пределах этих 320px

Comment: @Igor тогда делайте min-width не на html, а на общую обертку контента, у которой overflow-x: hidden включен всегда. Сделать для вас отдельный пример или сами догадаетесь?